# Linearity of the system with Pearson correlation sliding window

Tags: linear-systems, cross-correlation, statistics

I have a sampling system that consists of linear and non-linear components(analog filters, ADC, CPU, and so on). I made some HW changes and I want to verify that the linearity was preserved.

My method:

1. Record pure analog sine with some frequency $f$ and an amplitude $A$, get digital data in the output, call it $S$.
2. Generate synthetic sine wave $S^{'}$ with the same $f$ and $A$ using `scipy`. $len(S')$ is $n$ cycles of $S$.
3. Calculate Pearson correlation while sliding with $S'$ along $S$.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good way to test linearity?
2. What can I do with the set of coefficients from each window correlation? Take the mean, deviation, etc. or there are some advanced ways to look at the result.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for linearity in the sense of gain reduction as signal get large and you have compression, quantization effects, all of the above?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome, thank you for your question. I'm talking about linearity in terms of LTI. My system has some non-linear components like multiplexer(MUX), which interacts with linear components as LPF.  So I want to verify that my analog input(pure sine from FG) leads to a corresponding sampled sine as expected, and non of the non-linear components does not feed bad input through filters to ADC.